# Как конвертировать число из двоичной системы в десятичную

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть строка с числами от 0 до 15 в двоичном коде(4х битовом).Программа должна конвертировать этот код в обычные цифры и вывести на экран. Подскажите,как можно это реализовать?(желательно методом,похожим на мой пример)
В случае с текстом я делал так,но в этом случае 1 буква = 8 битов,а не 4.

```
string text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            text += out_txt[i].ToString(); // в out_txt записаны данные в двоичном коде
            byte[] ss = new byte[text.Length / 8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i += 8)
                ss[i / 8] = Convert.ToByte(text.Substring(i, 8), 2);
            text = "";
            text = Encoding.Default.GetString(ss);

            Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Пример строки :
 1101001110011110011011110111110110000011100111000000101010110100

Comment: А добавьте в вопрос пример ваших строк с двоичным кодом

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt64("1101001110011110011011110111110110000011100111000000101010110100", 2));`

Comment: @PetSerAl, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо,Ваш пример отлично работает. Если не трудно,можете подсказать как сделать конвертацию обратно? Т.е. из десятичной в двоичную систему(все способы что я попробовал конвертируют в 8бит,а не 4)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, идея может быть такая:

```
long ConvertToDec(string input)
        {
            long result = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
            {
                result += long.Parse(input[i].ToString()) * (long)Math.Pow(2, (input.Length - 1) - i);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Но в вашем примере, если руками делать, понадобится длинная арифметика.